# Second monitor won't work (via DisplayLink dock)

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, 18.04, displaylink, docking

I am trying to install WavLink's docking station (WL-UG93DK3) using DisplayLink's [instructions](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu), as directed from the WavLink website.  I'm following the instructions perfectly, and when running the .run file, the terminal throws this error:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dlm.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Job for dlm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dlm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**systemctl status dlm.service**:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dlm.service cha
● dlm.service - DisplayLink Manager Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dlm.service; static; vendor preset: enabl
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-05-14 06
  Process: 18027 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c modprobe evdi || (dkms install evdi/4.2
```

**journalctl -xe**:

```
~/Downloads/DisplayLink$ journalctl -xe
-- Unit dlm.service has finished shutting down.
May 14 06:25:00 DotyComp systemd[1]: Starting DisplayLink Manager Service...
-- Subject: Unit dlm.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dlm.service has begun starting up.
May 14 06:25:00 DotyComp sh[19956]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Re
May 14 06:25:00 DotyComp sh[19956]: Module evdi/4.2.29 already installed on kern
May 14 06:25:00 DotyComp sh[19956]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Re
May 14 06:25:00 DotyComp systemd[1]: dlm.service: Control process exited, code=e
May 14 06:25:00 DotyComp systemd[1]: dlm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
May 14 06:25:00 DotyComp systemd[1]: Failed to start DisplayLink Manager Service
-- Subject: Unit dlm.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dlm.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
May 14 06:25:01 DotyComp CRON[20036]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for
May 14 06:25:01 DotyComp CRON[20037]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || (
May 14 06:25:01 DotyComp CRON[20036]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for
lines 2336-2358/2358 (END)
```

I installed [this](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian) fix, but to no avail. Although the drivers are installed, I still don't have my multiple monitor functional on Ubuntu.  It works fine on the Windows side, so I know it's not a hardware issue.

**Driver verification**:

```
$ sudo displaylink-installer
DisplayLink Linux Software 4.2.29 install script called: 
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

**lsusb**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58e6 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 17e9:4307 DisplayLink
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I currently have only my keyboard and external monitor plugged into the dock, but my Logitech mouse isn't, however the mouse and keybard are in Bus 002, and the monitor isn't recognized.

**$ lsusb -s 002:**

```
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The FAQs link doesn't address this plethora of problems.  What did I do wrong?

*Computer stuff: HP Envy x360 laptop, dual-booting Win10x64 and 18.04x64, AMD® FX-9800P Radeon r7 (12 core), 8GB RAM*

Thank you in advance. -K